# How to create a background service to get all incoming SMS in Oreo?

Tags: android, service, sms, android-8.0-oreo

My program starts background service at boot using startForegroundService(intent) in Android >= Oreo, that service register a BroadcastReceiver and it listen to SMS_RECEIVED action. But service doesn't live for a long time, because of limitations. How to deal with it when I need constantly listen to SMS_RECEIVED action to not miss any SMS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service for foreground or NotificationListenerService.

Comment: As I understand NotificationListenerService is a service too? So, why it wouldn't be destroyed as my service now? What if the notifications on SMS will be switched off?